# Import another app's model

Tags: wagtail

What is the equivalent in Wagtail for importing another apps model? In Django I simply do `from app.models import SomeModel` but I can't figure out how to get hold of another apps model in Wagtail since they all inherent `from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page`

If I wanted to import `class HomePage(Page)` from home app in blog app... I've tried things like:

```
from project_name.home.models import HomePage
```

But it return a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name.home'`

Comment: Inheriting from `Page` shouldn't make any difference to the way you import them. What happens if you do it the standard Django way: `from home.models import HomePage`?

Comment: in the python console it works, it is just PyCharm that gives me a resolve error.

Comment: OK - in that case, you probably need to update PyCharm's configuration so that it knows the correct import paths. Unfortunately I don't use PyCharm, so I can't help with that...